Ошибка в создании бинов
У меня возникла проблема, уже 4 часа ломаю голову, прошу, помогите :(
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainGroupCommands' defined in file 
[D:\programming\bot\target\classes\com\bot\commands\MainGroupCommands.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mainPrivateCommands' defined in file 
[D:\programming\bot\target\classes\com\bot\commands\MainPrivateCommands.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.bot.commands.MainPrivateCommands]: Constructor threw exception

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MainPrivateCommands {

    private final MyWebhookBot bot = new MyWebhookBot();
    private final ProfileService profileService;

    // code...

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MainGroupCommands {

    private final MyWebhookBot bot = new MyWebhookBot();
    private final MainPrivateCommands privateCommands;

    // code...


Ну написано же Constructor threw exception. В конструкторе класса MainPrivateCommands выбрасывается эксепшен. Почему - без понятия, его кода нет.

Конструктор построен через ломбок, поэтому и кода нет. Что с ним я без понятия, поэтому и спрашиваю

Проблема для имеющегося кода, представленного в данном вопросе, НЕ воспроизводится.
Оба варианта Lombok-аннотаций @AllArgsConstructor и @RequiredArgsConstructor сгенерируют по одному конструктору с одним параметром для инициализации непроинициализированного финального поля:
// MainPrivateCommands
  public MainPrivateCommands(ProfileService profileService) {

    this.profileService = profileService;
  }

// -------
// MainGroupCommands
  public MainGroupCommands(MainPrivateCommands privateCommands) {

    this.privateCommands = privateCommands;
  }

и этого должно оказаться достаточным, чтобы Spring смог выполнить инъекцию через конструктор.
Финальное поле bot должно успешно проинициализироваться при создании обоих классов.
Однако, если где-то в коде имеются другие варианты конструкторов (например, отличающиеся типами параметров), а Спринг должен вызвать именно тот, что сгенерировал ломбок, то в параметре onConstructor соответствующей ломбок-аннотации следует указать, чтобы была дополнительно сгенерирована аннотация спринга @Autowired:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Service
public class MainPrivateCommands {
  private final MyBot bot = new MyBot();
  private final ProfileService profileService;
  // ....
}
// ------

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Service
public class MainGroupCommands {
  private final MyBot bot = new MyBot();
  private final MainPrivateCommands privateCommands;
}


Также можно явно указать порядок инициализации в конфигурации при помощи аннотации @DependsOn:
package com.mybot.config;

import com.mybot.commands.MainGroupCommands;
import com.mybot.commands.MainPrivateCommands;
import com.mybot.commands.ProfileService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

@Configuration
public class MyBotConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProfileService profileService() {
        return new ProfileService();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("profileService")
    public MainPrivateCommands mainPrivateCommands() {
        return new MainPrivateCommands(profileService());
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("mainPrivateCommands")
    public MainGroupCommands mainGroupCommands() {
        return new MainGroupCommands(mainPrivateCommands());
    }
}

